# Configure OIDC (OpenId Connect) identity provider to authenticate to SharePoint Online /Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, trusted-identity-provider, saml, openid-connect-protocol

Does anybody know how to configure OIDC (OpenId Connect) identity provider such as identity server 4 (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/) to authenticate to SharePoint online?

Looked at the following blog but it uses SAML 2.0 instead of OpenId Connect.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/azure-services/dn641269(v=azure.100)

Any body configured SharePoint Online with OpenID Connect identity provider?

Thanks.

Comment: SharePoint Online doesnt support OIDC for federated authentication but do support Saml2p. So i am here to confirm that Identity server 4 with Saml2p can be used as external identity provider for SharePoint Online.

Comment: Documentation from Microsoft says "The RSA-sha1 algorithm must be used as the DigestMethod. Other digital signature algorithms are not accepted.". This statement is not totally correct (at least now) because we used "RSA-sha256" algorithm and it worked.